# Need to process unicode characters in c#

Tags: c#, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

I have an application, where python source code with unicode characters from front end text box is attached to the body of an ajax request which is handled by Spring boot and queued in rabitMq server. This queue is consumed by C# console application and then feed to python executor using Pyrunner. the issue is it is throwing unicode error. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: `it is throwing unicode error` - and what, precisely, is this "unicode error"? What does your code look like?

Comment: You really need to localise the problem a bit. Which specific part throws this error? Try to reduce this to a minimal setup that still produces the problem, but is significantly more simple. Once you fix the problem in the simple version (we can help with that), you port the patch to the actual, complex setup to see if you fixed it.